# Ubuntu 12.10 screen starts flickering after reboot

Tags: 12.10, kernel

I have a Sony Vaio E series laptop. And I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on it. It was running all smooth without any problem, till I updated it (as we have to do after any normal installation of Ubuntu). But as I updated the system, it asked me to restart the system (which again is a normal thing), but after reboot, when the ubuntu 12.10 login screen came, it was all flickering.
Nothing was properly visible, though I heard the sound, when the login screen come's. 
Interestingly when I took the mouse to the top of the screen, it was partly visible. Also when I closed the lid the system went to sleep, and after resuming the screen was all Ok again.

But still, can you help with this problem of flickering.

Thank You!

Comment: Thanks for the work around - although not perfect, at least I can log in now!

Answer (score 0):

It's a kernel-related issue of kernel versions >=3.6.10 with your hardware.
Please report that the bug affects also you on Launchpad:
[Launchpad bug 1123024](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1123024)
This will rise the priority of the bug.